# Segmentation Fault in C: Infix to Postfix Evaluation

Tags: c, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I have written a program which converts expressions from arithmetic infix notation to postfix. There is no issue with this part of the program. After the conversion, the program should evaluate the expression and give a numeric answer by use of a stack.

The issue arises in line 232 when refering to `push2`, which gives a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV).

How can I resolve this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100 // maximum number of input characters

bool open_close(char opening, char closing);
bool check_balanced_par(char * exp, int length);

struct stack
{
    char my_stack[MAX];
    int pointer;
};

struct stack2
{
    float my_stack[MAX];
    int pointer;
};

int precedence(char x);
void push(struct stack *S, char *x);
char pop(struct stack *S);
void push2(struct stack2 *S, float *x);
char pop2(struct stack2 *S);

int precedence(char x)
{
    if(x == '#')
        return 0;
    if(x == '(')
        return 1;
    if(x == '+' || x == '-')
        return 2;
    if(x == '*' || x == '/')
        return 3;
    else
        return 4;
}

void push(struct stack *S, char *x)
{
    S->pointer++;
    S->my_stack[S->pointer] = *x;
}

char pop(struct stack *S)
{
    char data = S->my_stack[S->pointer];
    S->pointer--;
    return data;
}

void push2(struct stack2 *S, float *x)
{
    S->pointer++;
    S->my_stack[S->pointer] = *x;
}

char pop2(struct stack2 *S)
{
    char data = S->my_stack[S->pointer];
    S->pointer--;
    return data;
}

// checks to see if ()/[]/{} is the case
bool open_close(char opening, char closing)
{
    if (opening == '(' && closing == ')') return true;
    if (opening == '{' && closing == '}') return true;
    if (opening == '[' && closing == ']') return true;
    return false;
}

bool check_balanced_par(char * exp, int length)
{
    struct stack S;
    S.pointer = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if (exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '[')
        {
            S.pointer = S.pointer +1;
            S.my_stack[S.pointer] = exp[i];
        }
        else if (exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ']')
        {
            if(S.pointer == 0 || !open_close(S.my_stack[S.pointer],exp[i]))
                    return false;
            else
                S.pointer = S.pointer-1;
        }
        else if (exp[i] == '*' || exp[i] == '/' || exp[i] == '+' || exp[i] == '-' || isdigit(exp[i]))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
            return false; // if input is not as expected
    }
    if (S.pointer == 0) // checks if stack is empty
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


int main(void)
{
    char c;
    int size = 0;
    char arr[MAX];
    int o=0; // counter for arr[]

    printf("Enter an expression to check:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(arr, MAX, stdin);
    arr[strlen(arr)-1] = '\0'; // clears \n from array
    while((c=arr[o++]) != '\0')
    {
        size++;
    }

    if(check_balanced_par(arr, size))
    {
        printf("Balanced.\n");
        printf("Postfix notation is: ");

            struct stack S;
            struct stack *ptr; // pointer to stack
            ptr = &S; // setting the pointer
            S.pointer = -1;
            int z = 0; // counter to traverse input array
            char output[MAX]; // stores output
            int out_count = 0; // stores no. of characters of output

            char x = ' ';
            char y = '#';
            push(ptr, &y);

            while('\0' != arr[z]) // going through the input array and incrementing z everytime
            {
                if(isdigit(arr[z])) // if an operand is found print to screen
                {
                    output[out_count] = arr[z];
                    out_count++;
                }
                else if(arr[z] == '(') // if ( is found push on stack
                {
                    push(ptr, &arr[z]);
                }
                else if(arr[z] == ')') // if ) is found pop stack until ( is found
                {
                    while(!(S.my_stack[S.pointer] == '('))
                    {
                        output[out_count] = pop(ptr);
                        out_count++;
                    }
                    S.pointer--; // pop the extra (
                }
                else if(arr[z] == '*' || arr[z] == '/' || arr[z] == '+' || arr[z] == '-')
                {
                    push(ptr, &x); // used for correct output layout
                    while(precedence(S.my_stack[S.pointer]) >= precedence(arr[z]))
                    {
                        // pop stack
                        if(arr[z] == '(' || arr[z] == ')')
                            continue;
                        output[out_count] = pop(ptr);
                        out_count++;
                    }

                    // push arr[z] on stack
                    push(ptr, &arr[z]);

                }
                z++;
            }

            int j = S.pointer;
            while(S.my_stack[j] != '#')
            {
                if(S.my_stack[j] == '(')
                    continue;
                output[out_count] = S.my_stack[j];
                out_count++;
                j--;
            }

            output[out_count] = '\0';
            int k=0;
            while(output[k] != '\0') // go through output array and print
            {
                printf("%c", output[k]);
                k++;
            }

            // start evaluating the postfix format [THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS]
            struct stack2 T;
            struct stack2 *ptr2; // pointer to stack
            ptr2 = &T; // setting the pointer
            int i=0, l, g; // i counter for output[], l counter for nums[]
            float a,b;
            float toPush;
            float *ptr_toPush;
            char nums[MAX];
            char operator;
            float total;

            while(output[i++] != '\0')
            {
                if(isdigit(output[i]))
                {
                    l=0;
                    int y=i;
                    while(output[y] != ' ') // if character is not a space
                    {
                        nums[l] = output[y]; // place character in nums[]
                        y++;
                        l++;
                    }
                    i=y; // setting the counter for output[] to the character we have reached

                    toPush = atof(nums);
                    for(g=0; g<k; g++)
                        nums[g] = '\0';

                    ptr_toPush = &toPush;
                    push2(ptr2, ptr_toPush);
                }
                else if(output[i] == ' ') // if a space is found continue
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else // operator 
                {
                    a = pop(ptr);
                    b = pop(ptr);
                    operator = output[i];
                    switch(operator)
                    {
                        case '+':
                            total = a+b;
                            push2(ptr2,&total);
                            break;
                        case '-':
                            total = a-b;
                            push2(ptr2,&total);
                            break;
                        case '*':
                            total = a*b;
                            push2(ptr2,&total);
                            break;
                        case '/':
                            total = a/b;
                            push2(ptr2,&total);
                            break;
                        default: printf("Error.\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("Result is: %d", pop2(ptr2));
    }
    else
        printf("Not balanced.");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are never initializing the stack `T` before trying to push to it.

Comment: It means that one of your pointers is invalid at the time of call. You need to allocate memory for your stack.

Comment: Please see how to create [mcve]. We don't need to see all this code. You could for example use hard coded input; currently we don't know what input you are using.

Comment: Start by compiling with all warnings enabled.

Comment: ...and run it with your favorite debugger which will tell you _where_ the crash occurs.

Comment: You never initialize the `T` declared here `struct stack2 T`. Espectially `T.pointer` contains garbage. But  the way your code is written suggests that there are many other issues.

Comment: Another issue is, in the inner while loop of `while (output[y] != ' ')` you are not taking into the fact that y can go outside of the string, so better check like for instance `while (output[y] != ' ' && output[y]!= '\0') // CHECK FOR END OF THE STRING`

Answer (score 0):

After you define ptr2 (and any other stack pointer), use malloc to set it up properly. Also keep a pointer to the top of the stack so that when you pop, you do an error check to ensure that you have not popped too far. and so that you can free it properly when you no longer need it.